# Azure Web Role Shutdown (When and How?)

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

When the Azure platform decides to shut down one of my web role instances, how is that accomplished?

For example, does it stop sending new requests, but allows the existing requests to complete? I cannot imagine that it just terminates active connections for routine maintenance. That would be highly disruptive and costly.

Any insight into this little black box would be great, especially if you know of an MSDN or Azure CAT link that goes into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fabric Controller will remove the instance from the load balancer so it receives no new requests. It will then proceed to a clean shutdown sequence, first shutting down ASP.NET through its regular life cycle (will may vary depending on whether your application is running under integrated or classic mode), waiting for the requests to end (for up to the duration specified in the shutdownTimeLimit property), then raising the RoleEnvironment.Stopping event and calling the role's OnStop method for cleanup. At last, the Job Object will be terminated.

References:

- [Real World: Startup Lifecycle of a Windows Azure Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127476.aspx)
- [Overview of Building an Application that Runs in a Hosted Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/application-hosting/)
- [RoleEnvironment.Stopping Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.stopping.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [RoleEntryPoint.OnStop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx)
- [TerminateJobObject function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686709(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Health Application Pool Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720127(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [Process Model Settings for an Application Pool](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel)

Comment: Thank you! This is good information. Do you know if it will permit my active connections to be completed before it begins the clean shutdown?

Comment: I can't affirm that authoritatively. My understanding is that it will, because it will go through ASP.NET's regular shutdown cycle. I'll try and find that out from a Microsoft source.

Comment: Update: explained how IIS will wait for the requests to end for up to the time specified by the shutdownTimeLimit property (see references).